# draw a line with exact visual length in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to draw a line in qt to represent a road. To show the width of road, I set the width of line as corresponding value. However, the line shown in qt also seems longer duo to large width value. I know the line itself is drawn correctly, but how can I increase the width of line without affecting its visual length.
As shown in picture, I draw a black line between two yellow points, but there are additional parts outside yellow points.
[image: line in qt]

Comment: By thinking of it not as a line drawn with an increasingly wide paint-brush, but instead as a polygon that gets wider but no longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very difficult to comment without seeing your code.  However, assuming you are using a [`QPen`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpen.html) you might want to try...

```
pen.setCapStyle(Qt::FlatCap);
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: Thanks.That does work for me. BTW, I use  `Qt::FlatCap` instead of `QPen::FlatCap` in your code, since it seems `QPen`does not have `FlatCap`member.

Comment: @JiaweiLu Oops, mistake on my part.  Edited the answer to fix.